# Flutter Combo box and Number Input

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to make something where from a list a user can choose up to 4 inputs and then next to each list selection (combo box) is a number input which will correspond with a selected option in the combo box. Then I want to be able to select a button which will calculate the number input by a value defined by the selection in the corresponding combo box, does anyone know how to set that up in a flutter?

Comment: Hi @ogbainzy. Welcome to stackoverflow! I've read your question and I can't figure out what it is exactly that you're trying to do. I get that there's a combo box and an input, but it's not clear how the two of them are supposed to interact. I'd suggest making a small drawing depicting what you're trying to do to go along with your explanation if you're having trouble clarifying.

Comment: I also recommend sharing what you have so far for code as that'll help figure out what you're doing. And FYI - questions on Stack Overflow should typically be about a general problem that someone else could also benefit from in the future, rather than a specific problem that is important only to you. For example, a good question is along these lines: "I can't figure out how to get the value from a combobox. This <insert code, explanation here> is what I've tried so far, and this <insert explanation here> is why it isn't working".